# Closure of regular languages under deleting a 1 from each even run of 1s

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties

> Let $R$ be a regular set over the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$. Give a machine construction to prove that the set obtained by deleting one 1 from each even length block of 1’s is also regular, and using closure
>   properties for the class of regular sets.

Current Approach:

For the first part, using a machine construction, I was thinking that you take a simple FA that accepts only strings with an odd number of 1's (let's call this language $S$). This would be the simplest way of forcing strings in $R$ to have blocks of 1 of odd length. Then I would have some sort of $\epsilon/1$ transition to the original machines states where I would see if a string $x$ that is in the language $S$ would also be in $R$ if I were to add a 1 to any odd block of 1s.

I am unsure of how to describe that using the 5-tuple, $M = (Q, \{0,1\}, \delta, q_0, F)$, or if my methodology is correct. Any advice on where I should go and how I might prove closure in the two different ways is welcome.

Comment: Another way to look at it: L' is the language of all strings with no even length runs of 1's, which would be accepted by L if a 1 was added to none, some or all odd length runs of 1's. I think you should be able to generate a FSM for that.

Answer (score 4):

Below you can find solutions for the similar problem in which we want to delete a single 1 from each *odd* length run of 1s. I'll let you adapt them to your question.

First, let me explain how to solve it using closure properties. We start with your language $R$. We then apply a regular substitution that optionally "marks" every 1, i.e. changes it into $\mathbf 1$. We intersect the resulting language with $0^*((11)^*(\mathbf{1}+\epsilon)0^+)^*((11)^*(\mathbf1+\epsilon)+\epsilon)$ – this has the effect of marking the final 1 out of each odd run. Finally, we apply a homomorphism that deletes all marked 1s.

Second, let me explain how to explicitly construct an NFA for the new language given an NFA for $R$. Let the NFA for $R$ be $\langle Q, \{0,1\}, \delta, q_0, F \rangle$. The new states will be $(Q \times \{0,1\}) \cup \{q_f\}$, and the new initial state will be $\langle q_0, 0 \rangle$; the second entry is the parity of the current run of 1s. The new accepting states are $(F \times \{0\}) \cup \{q_f\}$ (note that in the new language, all runs of 1s must have even length). It remains to define the new transition function:

- If there is a transition $q_1 \stackrel 0 \to q_2$, then we add a transition $\langle q_1, 0 \rangle \stackrel 0 \to \langle q_2, 0 \rangle$; that is, we allow the transition only if the parity of the current run of 1s is even.
- If there is a transition $q_1 \stackrel 1 \to q_2$, then we add the following transitions:

  1. $\langle q_1, 0 \rangle \stackrel 1 \to \langle q_2, 1 \rangle$ and $\langle q_1, 1 \rangle \stackrel 1 \to \langle q_2, 0 \rangle$; these just maintain the parity of the length of the run.
  2. If $q_2 \in F$: $\langle q_1, 0 \rangle \stackrel \epsilon \to q_f$. This handles odd runs of 1s at the very end of input.
- If there are transitions $q_1 \stackrel 1 \to q_2 \stackrel 0 \to q_3$, then we add the transition $\langle q_1, 0 \rangle \stackrel 0 \to \langle q_3, 0 \rangle$. This corresponds to deleting a 1 from the end of an odd run.

Comment: For the claim that if $q_2 \in F$, the new transition is $(q_1, 0) \rightarrow q_f$ on $\epsilon$, why is this? Wouldn't it be $(q_2, 0) \rightarrow q_f$ on $\epsilon$?

Comment: The idea is that $q_f$ plays the role of $q_2$ here.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your clarification!